# set Interval only seems to happen once when appending a text node to a div

Tags: javascript

i want to add an underscore to the div element every second, it only appears to happen once.

Code:

```js
let input = document.createElement("DIV")
let space = document.createTextNode("_")

input.style.backgroundColor = "white"
input.style.width = "100%"
input.contentEditable = "true"

document.body.appendChild(input)

setInterval(function(){input.appendChild(space) }, 5000);
```

Comment: When an element is appended somewhere else, I think it gets moved, not copied.

Comment: I believe it won't let you append the same instance, change it to `input.appendChild(document.createTextNode("_"))`